# JQuery mobile application, JSON parsing

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

i have this JS code:

```
var actualDate;
var order;
var datatest;
var labels;
var lang;
var cached;

$.getJSON( "http://homel.vsb.cz/~mor03/TAMZ/cnb_json.php", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    //items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    //alert("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
    if(key==="date") actualDate=val;
    if(key==="order") order=val;
    if(key==="data") datatest=val;
    if(key==="labels") labels=val;
    if(key==="lang") lang=val;
    if(key==="cached") cached=val;

  });

alert(actualDate);
alert(order);
alert(datatest);
alert(labels);
alert(lang);
alert(cached);
});
```

My JSON look like:
{"date":"2017-03-27","order":"61","data":[{"country_label":"Austr\u00e1lie","curr_label":"dolar","unit":"1","code":"AUD","rate":"18.946"},
{"country_label":"Braz\u00edlie","curr_label":"real","unit":"1","code":"BRL","rate":"7.951"},
{"country_label":"Bulharsko","curr_label":"lev","unit":"1","code":"BGN","rate":"13.814"},
{"country_label":"\u010c\u00edna","curr_label":"renminbi","unit":"1","code":"CNY","rate":"3.609"},
{"country_label":"D\u00e1nsko","curr_label":"koruna","unit":"1","code":"DKK","rate":"3.632"},
{"country_label":"EMU","curr_label":"euro","unit":"1","code":"EUR","rate":"27.020"},
{"country_label":"Filip\u00edny","curr_label":"peso","unit":"100","code":"PHP","rate":"49.561"},
{"country_label":"Hongkong","curr_label":"dolar","unit":"1","code":"HKD","rate":"3.194"},
{"country_label":"Chorvatsko","curr_label":"kuna","unit":"1","code":"HRK","rate":"3.632"},
{"country_label":"Indie","curr_label":"rupie","unit":"100","code":"INR","rate":"38.153"},
{"country_label":"Indonesie","curr_label":"rupie","unit":"1000","code":"IDR","rate":"1.864"},
{"country_label":"Izrael","curr_label":"\u0161ekel","unit":"1","code":"ILS","rate":"6.866"},
{"country_label":"Japonsko","curr_label":"jen","unit":"100","code":"JPY","rate":"22.527"},
{"country_label":"Jihoafrick\u00e1 rep.","curr_label":"rand","unit":"1","code":"ZAR","rate":"1.964"},
{"country_label":"Ji\u017en\u00ed Korea","curr_label":"won","unit":"100","code":"KRW","rate":"2.237"},
{"country_label":"Kanada","curr_label":"dolar","unit":"1","code":"CAD","rate":"18.586"},
{"country_label":"Ma\u010farsko","curr_label":"forint","unit":"100","code":"HUF","rate":"8.710"},
{"country_label":"Malajsie","curr_label":"ringgit","unit":"1","code":"MYR","rate":"5.625"},
{"country_label":"Mexiko","curr_label":"peso","unit":"1","code":"MXN","rate":"1.318"},
{"country_label":"MMF","curr_label":"SDR","unit":"1","code":"XDR","rate":"33.823"},
{"country_label":"Norsko","curr_label":"koruna","unit":"1","code":"NOK","rate":"2.931"},
{"country_label":"Nov\u00fd Z\u00e9land","curr_label":"dolar","unit":"1","code":"NZD","rate":"17.528"},
{"country_label":"Polsko","curr_label":"zlot\u00fd","unit":"1","code":"PLN","rate":"6.337"},
{"country_label":"Rumunsko","curr_label":"nov\u00e9 leu","unit":"1","code":"RON","rate":"5.939"},
{"country_label":"Rusko","curr_label":"rubl","unit":"100","code":"RUB","rate":"43.671"},
{"country_label":"Singapur","curr_label":"dolar","unit":"1","code":"SGD","rate":"17.835"},
{"country_label":"\u0160v\u00e9dsko","curr_label":"koruna","unit":"1","code":"SEK","rate":"2.829"},
{"country_label":"\u0160v\u00fdcarsko","curr_label":"frank","unit":"1","code":"CHF","rate":"25.223"},
{"country_label":"Thajsko","curr_label":"baht","unit":"100","code":"THB","rate":"72.239"},
{"country_label":"Turecko","curr_label":"lira","unit":"1","code":"TRY","rate":"6.892"},
{"country_label":"USA","curr_label":"dolar","unit":"1","code":"USD","rate":"24.813"},
{"country_label":"Velk\u00e1 Brit\u00e1nie","curr_label":"libra","unit":"1","code":"GBP","rate":"31.273"}],"labels":["zem\u011b","m\u011bna","mno\u017estv\u00ed","k\u00f3d","kurz"],"lang":"cs","cached":true}

I dont understand why datatest variable contains only [Object object],[Object object],... etc.

How to parse it into some array of objects? I want each country in some object and i need access to their values like AllCountrys[].country_label or something like this.

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your "data" element in your returned JSON is an array of Objects. Thus, when you assign `datatest=val;` you are assigning an array of Objects to the datatest variable.

If you try `alert(datatest[0]["country_label"])` I expect you to see "Austr\u00e1lie" (properly encoded, of course).

Comment: Sure, great.. datatest[1].country_label is working. Ty

Comment: My pleasure - glad to be of help. Mark the answer as correct if you so believe (<-- shameless self promotion).

Comment: Sure, but you must wait :D your answer help too soon. It say i must wait 4 minute to mark the answer

Comment: Clearly I need to ask more questions - thank you for your honesty and hope you find great success with this project.